# What is the difference between Scheduling events and Time windows in Corda

Tags: corda

What is the exact difference between Sheduing Events and Transaction time windows in Corda

Answer (score 0):

1. **Time-Windows:** Imagine you have a state that represents a sales offer (e.g. a dealership is selling a car at a certain price); this offer might be limited (e.g. Christmas time offer), how do you represent that in Corda?
   It's a distributed system, nodes can be in different countries with different time-zones; which node has the correct data and time? That's why you can't have a point in time in Corda, you can only have time ranges, this range can be close ended (i.e. between this time and this time), or open ended (i.e. after this time, or before this time).
   And since the notary is the last entity that signs a transaction; the notary is the time-stamping entity in a Corda network.
   Back to our example, when you construct the transaction that creates the car sales offer, you can have an attribute in the offer that specifies the expiration date of the offer, then inside the flow that accepts (by the buyer) this offer; you can add a time-window with an open end (until expiration date minus 1 second).
   With the above setup, the notary will only sign if they received the fully signed transaction (remember that the flow will probably collect the signatures of the seller and buyer) before that time limit. So in short, the signature of the notary will testify that this offer was indeed accepted before the expiration date.
   You can read in detail about time-windows [here](https://training.corda.net/corda-details/time-windows/), you'll find an explanation, an exercise, and the solution of the exercise.
2. **Schedulable Events:** In Corda, you can have your state automatically trigger certain actions at a relative point in time; for instance you can have the sales proposal get cancelled by the seller once it expires; in order to do so, you specify that your state is a `SchedulableState` and you implement the `nextScheduledActivity()` method where you specify what action you want to happen and when.
   You can read in detail about schedulable events [here](https://training.corda.net/corda-details/automation/), you'll find an explanation, an exercise, and the solution of the exercise.